# Why could this graphical glitch happen in Blender?

Tags: objects, 3d-view, edit-mode, object-mode

I am using Blender for about 3 hours today, and I used it while live streaming.

Note that my CPU usage is mostly at 100% because I have a low-end PC.

---

And after that time I have encountered **this**:
[image: Model is stretching and have polygon glitch]
And this is what I get from my live stream footage:

### [image: Live stream footage]

I know my processor is overheating, but I don't know **how** this happens.

How is this happening? Is my processor slowly breaking? Is the data in my RAM corrupted? Or is it a completely different thing?
Please let me know so I can avoid this in the future.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, I hope you don't mind my edit, I hope it makes it a bit clearer. If you happen to not like it please forgive me and just change it back. How are you sure this is not caused by something you do in  Blender? Would it be possible for you to share the .blend file? Does the geometry change permanently, or does it just display like that?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about using Blender